# Joomla 1.7 htaccess configuration for localhost

Tags: joomla1.7

I installed XAMPP and joomla. I couldn't configure htaccess file for localhost. The htaccess code is here: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/53656/ I've been searching for ours and the solutions I found causes redireting to www.localhost.com

Comment: out of curiosity Why are you changing htaccess? it should work without it

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried to change it because rewriteengine hadn't work. but this code works fine: http://sudrap.org/paste/text/53763/

Answer (score 0):

That's better to add your link @nikel as an answer.
So here is the link that solve the problem:

[Complete htaccess which works like a charm](http://sudrap.org/paste/text/53763/)